# Accessing joined object in linq join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to do a fairly simple linq join like so:

```
var locations = (from location in session.Query<Location>()

                join speed in session.Query<ISDNSpeeds>() on location.ISDNSpeed equals speed.Id
                where 

                  (location.LastUpdatedTime > lastUpdateTime)

                select new
                {
                    Location = location,
                    Speed = speed,
                })
                .Take(10).ToList();
```

It seems to run without error, but I can't access the Speed object, I just get a list of location objects.

How would I access speed in this case?

Comment: You're saying there's no "locations.First().Speed" ? property on your anonymous type?

Comment: How are you accessing your Speed property? Can you show us the code you're using for that please. Also, the `x` at the end there, is that just a typo?

Comment: @DaveBish yes, that's what I'm saying, I'm new to this, so may be missing something obvious

Comment: It's ISDN, so you'll probably have to wait longer for the speed object to arrive. Apart from that, did you check (and run) the SQL that was generated?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a list of object in locations where you have property Location and Speed. Try `Console.WriteLine(locations.First().Speed);`

Comment: yes I am only getting a list of location objects. There is no Speed object to be seen

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically the same as the first example (Customers/Orders) on this page:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx

So the code you're using to access the results is probably wrong somewhere.